# Processing R sparse matrix (dgCMatrix) using C (not C++)

Tags: c, r, sparse-matrix

Can someone give me tips/pointers on how I could manipulate dgCMatrix class sparse matrices (from the `Matrix` package) using C? I have found some examples on processing using C++ (using `RCppEigen` notably), but haven't been able to find anything that tells me how I could do it using C. I am not familiar with C++ and intend to stick with C.

Some context: I am performing some operations on each row of huge sparse matrices (20kX100k). When I use a `for` loop to iterate through each row, it is very very slow. So I tried defining a function, and using `apply` on each row of the matrix - but `apply` gives me transpose of the matrix and also importantly the resulting matrix is not a sparse matrix anymore but regular matrix). So I am having to transpose this (non-sparse matrix) to get the matrix I need, and again convert this resulting matrix to object of `Matrix` class. Not very efficient to say the least, and hence I am looking to do what I want using C.